# How can I enable strict type checking on React component functional props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When declaring a React component that accepts a function as a prop, it seems that TypeScript is losing almost all type restrictiveness when passing in a function in the Parent scope.

In the example below, the child component `TestChild` has a single required prop `testFunction` which has a single parameter `testParam`. In the parent component `TestParent` declaration, though, the value passed into the child `testFunction` prop seems it can be almost anything (as long as it is a function). I've also tried this in a fresh `create-react-app --template typescript` project, and am experiencing the same issue.

How can I improve my TS configuration (or maybe even my ES linting rules) so that the TS compiler will require the parent component to pass in a function that adheres to the `testFunction` return value and `testParam` object shape?

```js
const dummyFunction = () => true;

// This does not throw an error when handing `dummyFunction` to the `testFunction` prop
const TestParent = () => <TestChild testFunction={dummyFunction} />;

interface TestChildProps {
  testFunction: (testParam: {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: Record<string, string>;
  }) => boolean;
}

const TestChild = ({
  testFunction,
}: TestChildProps) => {
  // No error thrown here as well - function type taken for granted as one defined within `TestChildProps` interface
  const test = testFunction({ foo: true, bar: { foo: 'bar' } });

  // As would be expected, calling the function here directly results in the TS error "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."
  const test2 = dummyFunction({ foo: true, bar: { foo: 'bar' } });

  return <h1>Hi</h1>;
};
```

TS version `4.2.3`, `tsconfig.json` values:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about which problem you're asking about? For the first one, note that `void` return on a function you're _receiving_ just means "I don't care what it returns", not "it must return nothing" (really undefined). And why would you expect `test` to have any other type, given it's calling the function with void return type? I *think* the key thing you're asking is "why is `testFunction={dummyFunction}` OK even though `dummyFunction` doesn't take the specified argument?", in which case: because JS doesn't really care about arity - it doesn't _declare_, but can _accept_.

Comment: Ah thank you - I'll update my question to remove any reference to `void`. The real question here is regarding function parameters and losing the strict type checking when passing functions from parent to child.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32789773/3001761 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/59325100/3001761, fundamentally - the React element (ha!) is irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm yeah in essence I think it might be a dupe of your second link. The TS docs link within the second answer was very illuminating https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions basically `y = x` in that example is `testFunction={dummyFunction}` in my example. Thank you very much for your help! Do you want to summarize that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Everything in your code is expected behavior.  You aren't losing anything.  `testFunction` can only be called with an argument of `testParam` type.  It does not have to *use* that argument. Like how an event handler can have no arguments even though it is called with the event.  @jonrsharpe's links explain that.